# Using OR statement within Query Importrange function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have a spreadsheet that I use to track orders for our business. Within this sheet, there's a cell that contains a data validation list with various statuses for the order.

I am attempting to set up a secondary sheet for our delivery person to view only orders that are currently anything other than "Delivered", "On Hold" or "Canceled" status.

Other statuses are "New", "Packed" and "Pending".

What I have so far is the following:

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("1CtEslspJ0qmsEc94q6RT6JW7ODxCrTK3MbI2wDF8BUE","'Order Tracker'!A:I"),
    "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col5, Col6, Col9 where Col3 = 'New'",-1)
```

This works great to pull all orders that are New, but obviously I need more than that. Not sure how to proceed because I tried inserting an OR() statement with the where Col3 is, but it spat errors no matter what I tried.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you could also create a drop-down list and reference them one by one, adding each variable when it is required.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is update your WHERE clause to use the word OR, not the function. So

`WHERE Col3 = 'New' OR Col3='Packed' OR Col3='Pending'`

I suppose to be technical and allow for other statuses you might focus on ANDing cases where it does not equal Delivered, On Hold, and Canceled.

```
WHERE Col3 != 'Delivered' AND Col3 != 'On Hold' AND Col3!='Canceled'
```